# react-native run-android > Error: Unknown Component MainActivity

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm running Arch Linux with Oracle JDK 7.

I can successfully

```
cd SampleAppMovies
react-native init SampleAppMovies
```

Now when I attempt

```
react-native run-android
```

I encounter:

```
Error: Unknown component: com.sampleappmovies/com.sampleappmovies.MainActivity
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: can you post the complete error log

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am struggling with the exact same one now.

Comment: Same problem here :/